# React change class attributes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to change class attribute in a function, I have a button and I want to change the text as soon as the user clicks it.
I wrote a class and everything but when the user clicks the button nothing happens!
I console logged to see if the variables actually changed and they did so why does it happen?

Here is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  loading: false,
  buttonStatus: 'Post room',
  value: '',
  }
}

PostANewRoomScreen = () => {
let {data} = '';
return (
<View style={{padding: 15}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      disabled={this.state.loading}
      onPress={() => this.postroom(data)}  
      >
      <Text style={{color: "white" , fontSize: hp('2.5%'), padding: 5}}>
      {this.state.loading && <Animated.Image style={{height: hp('3%'), width: wp('2%')}} source={{uri: 'https://media0.giphy.com/media/JTVkOqJ1RyYEBnyoRb/giphy.gif'}} />}
        {this.state.buttonStatus}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View> 

postroom = (value) => {
    this.state.loading = true;
    this.state.buttonStatus = "button clicked!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 this.state.loading = true;
this.state.buttonStatus = "button clicked!";
```

This does not re render component. You have to use useState Hook (in funcation component) or [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) (in class component) in order to update the state. I suggest converting component to functional component and use hooks to manage state.

```
const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('Post Room');
```

then use `setButtonStatus(value)` inside your postroom function.

Please refer react [doc for useSate Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Further, Your existing code has some issues. you are trying to access and mutate state of App component. if you need to share the component state try to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If you need to pass properties to component use [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Comment: I added the hook as you said but when I try to use the setButtonStatus() in the postroom(value) function I am getting this error:
setButtonStatus is not defined

Comment: @yarinCohen please find a working example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-meehdz?file=src/App.js  .